# SQL Server 2008: Modify xml replacing an attribute value with a value of a column

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008

I have a table:

```
declare @Table table (XmlPart xml, Cnt int)
```

the XmlPart is of the following form:

```
<Group count="0" />
```

I would like to modify XmlPart by substituting it with value of Cnt column. That's what I try:

```
update @Table
set XmlPart.modify('replace value of (/Group/@count)[1] with sql:column(Cnt)')
```

But the parser doesn't understand me..

Is it possible to substitute an attribute (or node value) of an xml with table column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You almost got it right :-)

```
update @Table
set XmlPart.modify('replace value of (/Group/@count)[1] with sql:column("Cnt")')
```

You need to put the column name in `sql:column` into double quotes...

See the [MSDN Docs on sql:column XQuery function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191214.aspx).